Covariant and contravariant components or biorthogonal system?
For context, these concepts are understood reasonably well. What I am after is a reconciliation between something that is purely geometric in the way of constructive Euclidean projections (with all the upside of being able to follow basic GR) and the more modern framework of more abstract differential geometry.
The question has now been migrated from Physics.SE, although I was interested in the physics community disentangling the confusion around this topic. So I hope there is some mathematician out there who can give some historical explanation to these kind of probably obsolete constructions. In the meantime, I have found a very similar question here without a great answer.
It boils down probably to a clarification to this answer. You can read my follow-up question there.

'Contra-variant' and 'co-variant' are terms variously applied to vectors (and tensors) to refer to the way they transform under a change of coordinates; also as synonyms of vectors and dual vectors (linear functionals); or the more routine geometric construction involved in obtaining contra-variant and co-variant components (parallelogram versus orthogonal projection) for either vectors or co-vectors.
In the common oblique coordinate system below, only one set of basis vectors is needed to obtain both the contra-variant (blue) and co-variant (red) components of $\vec v = a^1 \vec e_1 + a^2\vec e_2$. Clearly, $\vec v \neq a_1 \vec e^1 + a_2\vec e^2$, but importantly, $\vert \vec v\vert^2=a^1a_1+a^2a_2$.

A flashlight casting a shadow parallel or perpendicular to the coordinate axes is a perfect analogy from “A Student’s Guide to Vectors and Tensors” by Daniel A. Fleisch:

From $a_1=\vec v \cdot  \vec e_1$ and $a_2=\vec v \cdot  \vec e_2$, a simple substitution explains the lowering of indices by the metric tensor, since for instance $a_1=(a^1 \vec e_1 + a^2\vec e_2) \vec e_1$.
On the other hand, the bi-orthogonal system seems to call for two sets of basis vectors mutually orthogonal, in which case $\vec v = a_1 \vec e^1 + a_2\vec e^2= a^1 \vec e_1 + a^2\vec e_2$. This seems implied in answers like this one.

(From Wikipedia in here).
The squared norm cannot be calculated as above. The basis vector are related by $\vec e_1 \vec \varepsilon^2 = \vec e_2 \vec \varepsilon^1=0:$

Which one is it?

This is something often taught incorrectly in physics. A vector does not have two sets of components. You have a vector comprising components and basis. You also have its corresponding covector (i.e. in $V^*$) which also has components and basis one-forms. There is only one set of basis in each space.

I've followed your question here from P.SE. You have clearly not understood what Vincent Thacker correctly pointed out to you in the comment.
I also lament that this was moved from P.SE to M.SE; a mathematician might very well know the correct answer to this question, but even the very wording of your question is physics-based, inimical to a mathematician, and the mathematician would have a difficult time convincing you that their correct answer is correct, and that you are really barking up a wrong tree.

Standard physics is using really old and sloppy maths. There is actually a lot of distinctions between stuff and physics does not distinguish them. For example, what physics calls polar and axial vectors is just so wrong; axial vectors would, and should, differ in the transform, and really should not be treated as vectors at all. It would be much better to treat them as bivectors, as they are.
Anyway, focusing upon the physically well-motivated and well-defined polar vectors, the thing you want to deal with is then necessarily $\vec v=v^{\,x}\,\vec e_x+v^{\,y}\,\vec e_y$, that is, only contravariant components and covariant basis are defined. That is, whatever it is you want to draw as vector arrows, only contravariant vector components and covariant basis vectors are well-defined. There is no such thing as covariant vector components and contravariant basis vectors if you are strict with the mathematics.
This is not at all controversial. In the mathematics of differential geometry, you learn about one-forms, and that they are somewhat like density-of-layers in some layer cake, for the vector arrows to pierce through. You learn something like $\omega(\vec v)\in\mathbb R$, i.e. a one-form takes vectors as their arguments and returns numbers. Then, if you have a contravariant basis for these one-forms, you may decompose the generic one-forms as covariant components in terms of them, i.e. $\omega=\omega_x\varepsilon^x+\omega_y\varepsilon^y$, where $\omega_x$ and $\omega_y$ are the covariant components and the $\varepsilon$ are the contravariant basis. By definition, $\varepsilon^\alpha(\vec e_\beta)=\delta^\alpha_\beta$ (or in crystalline condensed matter physics, we prefer $2\pi\delta^\alpha_\beta$ so that the Brillouin zone is indexed nicer).
How does this tie into conventional standard physics? Well, it is good that you want to consider GR, because in GR, the curvature of spacetime itself means that there is no such thing as position vectors any more. This is important, so I have to repeat: Positions are not identify-able with vectors.
Instead, we get to lay down any coördinate system, subjected to consistency requirements. These coördinates are contravariant, by definition, so that velocity vectors, living in tangent spaces (the differentiation involved in defining tangent spaces thus linearise these spaces, allowing for the usual vector operations), inherit to have contravariant components with covariant vector basis.
$$\tag1\vec e_\beta=\left.\frac{\partial\ \ }{\partial x^\beta}\right|_{q\in M}\qquad\implies\qquad\varepsilon^\alpha=\mathrm dx^\alpha$$
When you write down the Lagrangian, you use the contravariant components to write the velocity and the position coördinates. Momentum is defined as $p_\alpha=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial v^\alpha}$; the denominator is the contravariant components, and so only the covariant components of momentum is a conserved quantity—this means that if you converted the momentum into contravariant components via the dual, or constructed some invariant momentum formulation, those are not conserved.
This means the horrible fact that, if we want to know which direction the momentum points, as in a vector arrow, we have to use the mathematical dual to find this arrow, but then it is not conserved. Yet, it is this not-conserved dual that defines the positive sign of the energy-momentum 4-vector one-form, i.e. $p^\alpha=g^{\alpha\beta}p_\beta=(E,\vec p)^T$ is the one that gets the conventional $E>0$, so that, depending upon your metric signature, $p_\beta=(-E,p^x,p^y,p^z)$ or $(E,-p^x,-p^y,-p^z)$

It is only after you accept all these facts, some of them really inconvenient, that you will understand that both the geometric construction and the bi-orthogonal system are wrong, and wrong for the same reason: they are trying to skip the real (annoying) physics, that is that the metric is the only true way to deal with these things, and instead are trying to use the availability of the dual to abuse the mathematics by a bit.
Namely, $\vec e_\beta$ exists, and $\varepsilon^\alpha$ exists, and they even satisfy $\varepsilon^\alpha(\vec e_\beta)=\delta^\alpha_\beta$. However, neither $\vec\varepsilon_\beta$ nor $\vec\varepsilon{}^\alpha$ exist. In particular, the metric tells us that $\vec e_\alpha\cdot\vec e_\beta=g(\vec e_\alpha,\vec e_\beta)=g_{\alpha\beta}$ is the real thing that exists, the real thing that lets you find $\vec u\cdot\vec v$, and so you cannot abuse and pretend that $\vec\varepsilon{}^\alpha\cdot\vec e_\beta=\delta^\alpha_\beta$ would work.
Of course, generations upon generations of physicists continue to pretend that $\vec\varepsilon{}^\alpha$ exists and satisfy the properties that we want of it, but if you push the mathematics too far, it will be slightly nonsensical. The transformation properties for the usual kinds that we subject them to, will happily work, but it will fail when you venture out of the standard few. And then, and only then, will you find yourself chasing down a hopeless rabbit hole. Still, the pretense is quite good for visualising the Brillouin zone, though.
